# I want to display Array from UITableView to the next viewController using didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I want the `quizNumber` to return the `quizNumberArray` depending on which cell is selected.

For example, if the user selected the first cell the `quizNumber` returns 1

Inside the UITableViewController

```
let quizNumberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var quizNum = Int()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "toQuestionVC") as? QuestionVC
    quizNum = quizNumberArray[indexPath.row]
}
    override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "toQuestionVC" {
            let questionController = segue.destination as! QuestionVC
            questionController.quizNumber = quizNum
}
```

in the next ViewController

```
class QuestionVC : UIViewController {
    var quizNumber = Int()
    func updateQuestion(){
        if quizNumber == 1 {
            //.....
        }
    }
}
```

But the `quizNumber` return 0.

Comment: When you are pushing to QuestionVC? in didselect itself??

Comment: No, using segue

Comment: so you have to pass value there or push from didselect

Comment: How i can pass value there?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `prepare`?

Comment: Have you tried perform for segue? @Tameem

Comment: @Shezad@juniorRubyist@teja_D I've edited the question

Comment: Instead of initializing the quizNumber variable, you should only declare it as an implicit optional (`var quizNumber: Int!`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "toQuestionVC") as? QuestionVC
     vc?.quizNumber = quizNumberArray[indexPath.row]
     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}
```

and remove the segue to work the above code

Comment: I'm using the segue to pass data.Is there another way?

Comment: @Tameem but you will get only value in didselect right so i think the above method is better or else you have to save index in a variable and pass it in segue.

Comment: @Shazed I have another data to pass through the segue so I tried to save index in a var `var quizNum = Int()`  in didSelectRowAt `quizNum = quizNumberArray[indexPath.row]` and in func prepare for segue `let questionController = segue.destination as! QuestionVC
                questionController.quizNumber = quizNum` but it's not working

Comment: @Tameem i think its because it might be calling segue method before didselect, so pass all the values you wanted in didselect itself. and remove segue

Comment: @Tameem Push is actually deprecated, i prefer you to use show.